# Creating and Starting Tasks inside a Foreach

Tags: c#, closures, task

I was trying to scrape some data from a site. Here is my class:

```
class ClosureCraziness
{
    public string SaveFolder { get; set; }

    public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> idToWebLocation)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var kvp in idToWebLocation)
        {
            var task = new Task(() => Download(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            task.Start();
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    void Download(string id, string location)
    {
        var filename = $"{id}.html";
        string source = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            source = GetSource(location);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(SaveFolder, filename);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
            sw.Write(source);
    }

    string GetSource(string location)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString(location);
        }
    }
}
```

When I executed, I would wind up with something like the following. You'll notice that the contents of the file (the source that was downloaded) does not match the name:

Filename on Disk   | `File Contents`

apple.html          `<html> apple </html>`

orange.html         `<html> orange </html>`

pear.html           `<html> peach </html>`

peach.html          `<html> peach </html>`

grape.html          `<html> apple </html>`

plum.html           `<html> plum </html>`

(I can't figure out how to format this nicely)

At first I was baffled since the file name on the disk was correct, and I was sure my `Dictionary<string, string>` was properly formed (I checked 6 times, all different ways), meaning the association of Id to web location was good.

I thought maybe it was a closure issue, having recalled [Eric Lippert schooling me on the implementation of foreach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/). So I tried:

```
public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> idToWebLocation)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var kvp in idToWebLocation)
    {
        var innerKvp = kvp;
        var task = new Task(() => Download(innerKvp.Key, innerKvp.Value));
        task.Start();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

And, to be safe:

```
public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> idToWebLocation)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var kvp in idToWebLocation)
        {
            var innerKvp = kvp;
            var id = innerKvp.Key;
            var loc = innerKvp.Value;
            var task = new Task(() => Download(id, loc));
            task.Start();
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
```

Also, because who knows:

```
public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> idToWebLocation)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var kvp in idToWebLocation)
    {
        var innerKvp = kvp;
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            var id = innerKvp.Key;
            var loc = innerKvp.Value;
            Download(id, loc);
        });

        task.Start();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

But neither of those worked. Clearly my understanding of how this code gets compiled is lacking, but I mean, what the hell is going on.

It seems like somewhere between `var filename = $"{id}.html";` and `source = GetSource(location);` that `location` is changing. I'm pretty sure the code is thread safe, there is no shared state, right?

But obviously it's not, because when I iterate through the dictionary synchronously everything works exactly as expected.

Maybe I'm missing some fundamental point here, regarding enclosures or threading or memory or whatever. I don't know, but my desk is covered in hair and I'm approaching baldness.

Comment: If you suspect the dictionary to be a problem with threading (I don't think it is either, it does not participate in the parrallel execution), try ConcurrentDictionary. And have a good look at the source files, do they really have the content you expect them to?

Comment: @MartinMaat They don't have the content I expect, that's the problem. Unless you mean when I run synchronous, in which case, yes, I examined them very closely. Also - I can't imagine how the dictionary is the issue here.

Comment: It's C# 6 ($"you can see the string {interpolation} at use here" - which is amazing) compiled against .NET 4.5.2. But I don't really think it's a closure issue anymore. Maybe. I don't know.

Comment: Perhaps you should try the old school `String.Format()` to see if that makes a difference. I'd guess the `$"{key}"` format is syntactical candy for the same thing, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot about you mentioning it does work synchronously. Try putting access locks around the code in the download method. If it works, narrow it down by locking less.

Comment: Also something worth mentioning, but do you control the website you're scraping that download from? Is it possible that there is some session-level issue at the source site that's pushing down the same file if a download is performed concurrently?  I've seen weirder things. :)

Comment: Yeah, good point from MNCM. Try "downloading" local files instead.

Answer (score 1):

The task parallel library has a for each method designed very much for the kind of thing you're doing.  You might find that interesting/relevant to what you're currently trying to do:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the Dictionary is only being used on one thread.

Comment: You know what? You are correct.  That is, assuming you're not modifying that Dictionary in another thread outside of your Save() workflow (modified closures are bad).  I will change my answer to remove the concurrent dictionary, but you might want to check out the TPL's for-each partitioned workflow. It's designed for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to create local variables of key and value before creating a task.

```
var key = kvp.Key;
var value = kvp.Value;
var task = new Task(() => Download(key, value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the problem if you change the code to use async/await instead of constructing the tasks yourself?

```
class ClosureCraziness
{
    public string SaveFolder { get; set; }

    public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> idToWebLocation)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var kvp in idToWebLocation)
        {
            tasks.Add(Download(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    async Task Download(string id, string location)
    {
        var filename = $"{id}.html";
        string source = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            source = await GetSource(location);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            filename = "e-" + filename;
            var ex = e;
            while (ex != null)
            {
                source += ex.Message;
                source += Environment.NewLine;
                source += Environment.NewLine;
                source += ex.StackTrace;
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(SaveFolder, filename);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
            await sw.WriteAsync(source);
    }

    async Task<String> GetSource(string location)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(location);
        }
    }
}
```

The only things I've changed from your original are to use the `Task` returning versions of `Write` and `DownloadString`, change your helper methods to return `Task`s, and pepper in some `async`s and `await`s to make the code compile. I don't have a compiler handy, but this should be pretty close to correct.

I don't actually see the problem with your original, but by encapsulating the task creation in a function that takes its inputs as parameters, we should be able to minimize the possibility of closure-related bugs creeping in.